# How do you report Bugs

Tags: support

I've encounted a bug on the Stack exchange sites, how do i report it or more so who do i report it too? If this is the wrong place to ask please can you link me to the right place to ask the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a bug with this site only then you report it here and use the bug tag (as you've done with this question). If it's one that happens across all the sites then report it on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ but please make sure that you check if someone's already reported it.